# Which metric to use to evaluate and compare meta models?

Tags: machine-learning, python, model, model-evaluation, model-comparison

I'm developing meta models based on Zero Inflated Model (`sklego.meta.ZeroInflatedRegressor`)
That is, they are models that have two tasks to perform:

1. Train a classifier to tell us whether the target is zero, or not. If the classification is not zero, then...
2. Train a regressor on all samples with a non-zero target.

Code example:

```
    #build the model
    model = ZeroInflatedRegressor(
    classifier=ExtraTreesClassifier(random_state=0),
    regressor=ExtraTreesRegressor(random_state=0))

    r2 = cross_val_score(model, scaled_train, y_train.values.ravel(), scoring = 'r2')
```

Initially, I thought about using R², but I'm not confident in my choice.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

NOTE: my data are time series. Maybe this makes some difference.

Comment: Is the output of your models a predictive distribution (AKA a density forecast)? Do you plan on evaluating it on a holdout sample?

Comment: @StephanKolassa, yes it is a density forecast. My goal is to predict whether a count equals 0 or not. and if it is different from 0, what is the value of this count. I apply a Time Series cross-validator, but I am not using a separated holdout sample to evaluate the model.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your outcome is a predictive density (i.e., for each future point in time, you predict the probability for an outcome of $0$, the probability for an outcome of $1$ and so forth), the standard evaluation metric is a *proper scoring rule*. We have a [scoring-rules](/questions/tagged/scoring-rules) tag, and [the tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info) contains more information and pointers to literature. Much of the scoring rules literature indeed happens in a time series forecasting context, see e.g., the papers by Gneiting and coauthors.